# How to get the coefficient from a std::decimal?

Tags: c++, c++11, decimal

**Background**

I want to write an *is_even( decimal::decimal64 d )* function that returns true if the least-significant digit is even.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any methods to extract the *coefficient* from a *decimal64*.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <decimal/decimal>

using namespace std;

static bool is_even( decimal::decimal64 d )
{
    return true;  // fix this - want to: return coefficient(d)%2==0;
}
int main()
{
    auto d1 = decimal::make_decimal64( 60817ull, -4 );   // not even
    auto d2 = decimal::make_decimal64( 60816ull, -4 );   // is even

    cout << decimal64_to_float( d1 ) << " " << is_even( d1 ) << endl; 
    cout << decimal64_to_float( d2 ) << " " << is_even( d2 ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AFAICT, `std::decimal` is not (yet) standard. So, you are going to have to tell us which version of the implementation of which draft/proposal/TR you are talking about.

Comment: FWIW, in [this TR paper](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf) I can't find a built-in way to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little odd that there's no provided function to recover the coefficient of a decimal; but you can just multiply by 10 raised to its negative exponent:

```
bool is_even(decimal::decimal64 d)
{
    auto q = quantexpd64(d);
    auto coeff = static_cast<long long>(d * decimal::make_decimal64(1, -q));
    return coeff % 2 == 0;
}

assert(!is_even(decimal::make_decimal64(60817ull, -4)));
assert(!is_even(decimal::make_decimal64(60816ull, -4)));
```

Comment: That was my 1st bet, although I think instead of `d * make_decimal64(1, -q)` one could use `quantized64(d,make_decimal(0,0))`. Well, it probably has your implementation, so maybe there is no difference.

Comment: For g++ 4.9.1, I can't seem to find `quantexpd64()` in cmath or math.h.  Is there a later version that implements it or is there an open source implementation somewhere that I can use?

Comment: @kfmfe04 as far as I can tell libbid and libdecnumber implement quantize and samequantum but not quantexp.

Answer (score 1):

I would use corresponding `fmod` function if possible.

```
static bool is_even( decimal::decimal64 d )
{
    auto e = quantexpd64(d);
    auto divisor = decimal::make_decimal64(2, e);
    return decimal::fmodd64(d, divisor) == decimal::make_decimal64(0,0);
}
```

It constructs a `divisor` that is `2*10^e` where `e` is exponent of the tested value. Then it performs `fmod` and checks whether it is equal to a decimal `0`. (*NOTE: `operator==` for decimal is said to be `IEEE 754-2008` conformant so we don't need to take care of -0.0*).

An alternative would be to multiply the number by `10^-e` (to "normalize" it) and cast it to an integer type and traditionally check modulo. I think this is [@ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567292/ecatmur)'s proposal. Though the "normalization" might fail if it goes out of chosen integer type bounds.

I think `fmod` is better when it comes to overflows. You are guaranteed to hold `2*10^e` given that is a proper `d` decimal (i.e. not a `NaN`, or an `inf`).

One caveat I see is the definition of least significant digit. The above methods assume that least significant digit is denoted by `e`, which sometimes might be counterintuitive. I.e. is `decimal(21,2)` even? Then is `decimal(2100,0)`?

Comment: If I may ask, what are the headers for quantexpd64(), decimal::fmodd64()?  I'm trying to compile this under g++ 4.9.1, but I can't seem to find quantexpd64() in cmath...

Comment: I used this TR http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf as a reference. As others have mentioned, this is not standard, there is no guarantee anything is implemented. Sadly. On the other hand... Maybe it is not that hard to implement by yourself... It is hard to tell what best alternative is